# Can MSSQL server be configured to create a database in a specified folder?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008. Each time when I create a new database with it, it attempts to the database in the destination folder like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

I understand that I can manually change it. But I am curious whether the default destination folder can be configured to another folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured in the Database Settings of the Server Properties:

[image]